# Assign code to column header instead of column cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

everyone, I need help, I would like to assign my code to the column header instead of column cell. But I do not know how I can do it.

These are some information

```
Worksheet = "Export Worksheet"    
Column 14's header = "PACKAGE"    
Column 10's header = "DAY_SCHEDULE"    
Column 11's header = "START_TIME"    
Colum 27's header = "LUNCH"
```

### Following is my coding without any assigning of code to the column header. Please help!

```
Sub Lunch()

Dim i, NumberOfRows As Integer

   With ActiveSheet
    NumberOfRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
   End With

For i = 2 To NumberOfRows
    If (((Cells(i, 14).Value <> "" And Cells(i, 14).Value = Cells(i + 1, 14).Value) And (Cells(i, 10).Value = Cells(i + 1, 10).Value) And (Cells(i + 1, 11).Value - Cells(i, 11).Value) > 120)) Then
        Cells(i, 27).Value = "TRUE"
    Else
        Cells(i, 27).Value = "FALSE"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: "Assign code to column header" - what do you exactly mean? Why do you need that? As you word it currently is neither possible, neither makes sense to do it. Please share a bit more background.

Comment: @MátéJuhász As in, the instead of writing the column (eg: column 2) into the code, I want to change it into the header name itself. So that, if i shift the column to another column, the code will not be affected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get you what you're looking for:

```
Sub Lunch()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim NumberOfRows As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Package As Variant
    Dim DaySchedule As Variant
    Dim StartTime As Variant
    Dim Lunch As Variant

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

'Set Variables
    Package = Application.Match("PACKAGE", ws.Range("1:1"), 0)
    DaySchedule = Application.Match("DAY_SCHEDULE", ws.Range("1:1"), 0)
    StartTime = Application.Match("START_TIME", ws.Range("1:1"), 0)
    Lunch = Application.Match("LUNCH", ws.Range("1:1"), 0)

'Check for missing headers
    If IsError(Package) Or IsError(DaySchedule) Or IsError(StartTime) Or IsError(Lunch) Then
        MsgBox "One or more of the required headers are missing!", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With ws
        NumberOfRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'Main Loop
        For i = 2 To NumberOfRows
            If (((.Cells(i, Package) <> "" And .Cells(i, Package) = .Cells(i + 1, Package)) And _
                    (.Cells(i, DaySchedule) = .Cells(i + 1, DaySchedule)) And _
                    (.Cells(i + 1, StartTime) - .Cells(i, StartTime)) > 120)) Then
                .Cells(i, Lunch).Value = "TRUE"
            Else
                .Cells(i, Lunch).Value = "FALSE"
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

This assumes your column headers are in row 1.